# Simulating circuit TINA TI

Tags: voltage, diodes, zener, semiconductors, tina

For my assignment I got to run a transient analysis for the duration of 5 periods of sinusoidal input voltage and display the input voltage (ac + dc) and the output voltage on the RL component.
Used components are : (VSIN)-amplitude 5 V and frequency 60 Hz, DC voltage
(VDC) amplitude 20 V, resistor R = RL = 500 Ω,  Zener diode D1N750 and ground
(GND_EARTH) (First picture)

I do not know how to set number of periods of sinusoidal input to five and how to get
comparison of the input and output voltages like the one shown in the second picture.
Thank you in advance.

[image: First picture]

[image: Second picture]

Comment: Set the run time to be 83.333333 ms

Comment: Thanks .Do you know how to get diagram with both input and output voltages, there is only one  shown in the scheme I got?

Comment: Never used it..